# Is it safe to set my water heater tank to vacation during winter time? What else can I turn off to save heating bills during winter?

Tags: electrical, water-heater, heat, water-tank, winter

Is it safe to turn set my water heater tank to vacation during winter because I am mostly away from my house?  I live in Canada.

What else can I turn off to save heating bills during winter when I am away at my house?

Comment: Does the building need to be kept heated to prevent damage to the foundation? Many slab-on-grade buildings do.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should turn off the water to the house and water heater . I've had a burst pipe at my vacation home because the power failed, it got really cold and froze pipes. When the power came back on and melted the frozen water in the pipes, there was a badly cracked pipe that did a ton of damage.   If you have pex plumbing that doesn't apply, but if it's copper or steel, you are at risk. Even if you did have a metal pipe freeze and burst, when you came back and turned on the water, it would probably be immediately obvious that you had a burst pipe that you could address immediately, mitigating further damage.

I would also set the heating system (not sure what you have, so take this with a grain of salt) to about 45 F. That's high enough to keep the humidity in check, but shouldn't be too costly.

Comment: That's overkill if the house is kept heated.

Comment: Frozen pipes effects PEX too - the joints.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Frozen pipes aren't the only reason pipes burst.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica please elucidate!   The only thing that causes a burst is overpressure -- are you suggesting there's a risk of some external event leading to overpressure, or of a runaway hot water heater causing steam & the overpressure valve sticking and so on?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft joints also fail, very rare, but it happened to me a poorly soldered joint at my vacation home, right next to the water heater started failing, with a small but steady stream of hot water spraying out into the garage for who knows how long.  It's such a simple task to turn off the water when you're not there.

Comment: @carl fatigue cracking, water hammer (think automatic device like a water softener, they love to make water hammer), corrosion, marginal joint letting go, non-lead solder crystallization, gasket perishing, plastic part in an appliance perishing, accelerated corrosion due to anode end of life, you name it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Great list of potential failures, way more than I would have thought of. Like I said in an earlier comment, it's such a small task to turn off the water and eliminate all those risks. +

Comment: If the water supply is turned off, what's the point of also turning off the valve at the water heater?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you are completely shutting down your house, then you need to drain all the pipes, put antifreeze into all the traps, and so on.

**edit**
Based on the discussion in comments under George's answer, I'll add that the choice depends on how long you will be away.  If you plan on coming up every couple weeks or so, then it doesn't really make sense to do a full drain (but cutting off the main source valve is wise; or turning off your pump if that's the source).  But if this is a full-season shut down, then I agree with draining the system.  For that matter, disconnect any electrical item capable of generating heat (toaster, coffeemaker, etc) just to be absolutely safe.

However, if you are keeping the heating system running, and verify that the temperature at all pipe locations will remain above about  5 degrees C, then there's no reason to have the water heater left on at all.  The risks are the same for hot-water pipes and cold-water pipes when you don't drain the system.

By the way, I strongly recommend at least an internet-connected thermostat, which will email you or a local service company if the house temperature drops below a warning level.  You could go further and install internet (or alarm)-connected moisture sensors to check for possible pipe leaks at standard locations like entry into the house or where pipes go into outer wall cavities.

Comment: Carl:  I completely agree with you regarding the internet connected tstat.  I actually have one at my vacation home and it's very comforting to check on it once in a while.  Like you said, it also sends me alerts if the temp drops too low.  I haven't set up a leak detector (cabin minder) yet, but will probably do so as well. Take care and stay safe!.